# Replacing text with blanks OSX Sed

Tags: bash, sed

My file has 2 times stamps in every line. I would like to delete the +0800 in every line using sed. I have tried the following command labelled "command used"

```
Example input    
2020-11-17 08:50:42.614276+0800 2020-11-17 08:50:42.000000+0800

Command used
sed -E 's/\+\d{4}//g'

Actual Output (same as input)
2020-11-17 08:50:42.614276+0800 2020-11-17 08:50:42.000000+0800

Expected Output
2020-11-17 08:50:42.614276 2020-11-17 08:50:42.000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
sed -E 's/\+[0-9]{4}//g'
```

or

```
sed -E 's/\+[[:digit:]]{4}//g'
```

instead, as `sed` does not recognize `\d`.

Comment: Thanks for this! It didn't even throw an error so I thought it would be ok. So would the regex have been searching for "\d" in the pattern space

Comment: And as you can verify `grep -E '\+\d{4}'` works